# How do I connect to AWS RDS SQL Server from AWS Lambda .Net Core application API?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an Angular app in S3 calling a .Net Core app in Lambda. An API in the Lambda .Net Core app runs against a RDS SQL Server.

I get a 504 error returned from the .Net Core app in Lambda when it tries to interact with RDS, but not if I comment out the C# code that calls the database.

I can connect fine to the RDS database on AWS when I am running the Angular app and .Net Core app locally, which demonstrates that the connection string to the RDS DB works. (Local IP address is same as used to create RDS SQL Server.)

When running nothing locally, I am getting a POST 504 error. Further info says: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/myapi' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What do I have to do to successfully connect to my SQL Server database from my Lambda .Net Core app's api?

Comment: You need to add details to your question, like is the Lambda function running in a VPC? Is it the same VPC as the RDS instance? Have you configured the Lambda function with a security group and given that group access to the RDS instance? Are there any log messages in the Lambda function's CloudWatch Logs when the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think connecting to RDS is your problem, the problem is that your reactfiles are not on the same domain that Lambda function is on. That causes the 504.
The quickest solution is setting an CORS policy on the server. You can easily configure that in the api-gateway. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#apigateway-responding-to-cors-preflight

Comment: The Lambda function works fine from Angular, unless that Lambda function is trying to connect to the RDS. I mentioned that in the post.